# Use of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

C program from books:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *addition ( int a , int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    int *d = &c;
    printf("%d %d, ",c, &c);
    printf("%d %d, ",d, *d);
    return d ;
}

int main (void) {
    int result = *(addition(1,2));
    int *result_ptr = addition(1,2);

    ////

    printf("result_ptr = %d\n" , *result_ptr ) ;
    printf("result = %d\n" ,result) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

when I swaps last two Line , the program becomes buggy.

Question.
 addition() should return a pointer or not?

I fix it by change the `*result_ptr` to result_ptr.
And also the addition() is not a pointer ,but why?

Comment: Unless that program is meant to be a puzzle for you to solve (i.e. find the bug) you should throw the book away.

Comment: Can you comment the lines 15 and 16 that you have mentioned ?

Comment: are you pulling the return statement up?

Comment: Holy cow... that's actual code from an actual book?!?

Comment: You should allocate the memory to pointer variable C on heap in order to return it by your method and access inside main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable `c`. This variable is allocated on stack, which means that it is not valid after the `addition` function returns.

`addition` should simply return an integer, no need for pointers here.

Comment: That means the program does not really return pointer?
it just a integer.right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. `addition` indeed returns a pointer, but it is a pointer to `c` variable which is destroyed as soon as `addition` exits, so when you read from the pointer you get garbage. You should change addition to return just an `int`: `return a + b;`

Answer (score 4):

You have undefined behavior in that you return a pointer to a local variable. When the function returns this pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: Yea, and if you swap lanes the call to the function overwrites the stack.